# How to print in Arduino a char variable as a number to the Serial Port?

Tags: arduino, char, serial-port, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am using Arduino Uno. I am reading a byte value from the EEPROM and storing the value in a variable of type `char` (1 byte).

I want to print the value of the variable as a number (not to the corresponding ASCII code) to the Serial Monitor. For example consider `char val = 5`.
I want to see to the Serial Monitor `5` and not the ASCII value.

I tried both `Serial.print(val)` and `Serial.write(val)` but the result is the same: it prints always the ASCII code.

How can I print the value to the Serial Monitor?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried it did not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast the `char` variable to an `unsigned char` type:

```
Serial.print( (uint8_t) c );
```

This calls a different `print` method.  They are "overloaded".

Answer (score 0):

store the variable as type byte instead.

```
byte val = 5;
```

then `Serial.print(val)` will give 5

Answer (score 0):

Other two answers that suggest using `byte` or `uint8_t`(they are equal) , but those two data type are both ***unsigned***,ranging from 0 to 255. If you want to print negative numbers, you can try this way:

```
char x=-1;
Serial.print(x,DEC);
```